# GROUP BY to get several aggregates per row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table GAMES where I have the ids of player_1, player_2 and the winner

```
player_1   player_2   winner
1          2          1
1          2          1
1          3          3
2          3          2
2          1          2
```

I want to make a query where the end result would be similar to:

```
players     num_games_played   wins  
1|2         3                  2|1
1|3         1                  0|1
2|3         1                  1|0
```

Basically I need to group by the results to show a list of games played and number of wins per player.

I'm not really sure whether I should stick with this sort of table or make some relationship tables.

Any suggestion of how the best approach would be?

Comment: Step 1: Make sure player1 < player2. (case, or union all)

Comment: What would make one approach "better" than another for purposes of your question?

Comment: Basically I would assume there would be an "easy" way to make this aggregation that I'm probably missing... My current query is currently definitely lacking elegance...

Comment: What's your current query?

Comment: It's a mess with subqueries...

Comment: The main question is how to get all combinations of your players.

Comment: graph database is a good candidate for this. goodluck!

Comment: My approach has been to Subquery a games_players table but I would imagine there would be a better approach

select
  id,
   LTRIM(STUFF((SELECT '|' + CAST(gp.userf AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM games_players gp WHERE g.id = gp.gamef
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) players

from games g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can tackle this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Games') is not null
    drop table #Games

create table #Games
(   
    player1 int
    , player2 int
    , winner int
)

insert #Games values
(1, 2, 1)
, (1, 2, 1)
, (1, 3, 3)
, (2, 3, 2)
, (2, 1, 2)

select players = convert(varchar(5), player1) + '|' + convert(varchar(5), player2)
    , num_games_played = count(*)
    , convert(varchar(5), sum(case when winner = player1 then 1 else 0 end)) + '|' + convert(varchar(5), sum(case when winner = player2 then 1 else 0 end))
from
(
    select player1
        , player2
        , winner
    from #Games
    where player1 < player2

    union all

    select player2
        , player1
        , winner
    from #Games
    where player2 < player1
) x
group by convert(varchar(5), player1) + '|' + convert(varchar(5), player2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some relational tables, It will be easy for you to get the results and also will help you if you later make some updates that allows from more than two players. Maybe one table with the game/match information and another table linked to the game table where you have the players that played the match and a bit field for the result (winner).

Answer (score 0):

This is another code which is using similar ideas from above SQL query

```
with demo_solution as (
select 
p1=case when player1>player2 then player2 else player1 end,
p2=case when player1>player2 then player1 else player2 end,
winner
from Games
)
select 
players = cast(p1 as varchar)+'|'+cast(p2 as varchar),
num_games_played = count(1),
wins = cast(sum(case when winner=p1 then 1 else 0 end) as varchar)
     +'|'+
    cast(sum(case when winner=p2 then 1 else 0 end) as varchar)
from demo_solution
group by cast(p1 as varchar)+'|'+cast(p2 as varchar)
```